# NiFi data safety in case of processor down due to any reason

Tags: java, apache-nifi

If any processor get a data from queue, start processing and that time processor goes down for any reason. Then what happens with particular data (data is lost or safely keep into the some other queue)?

Comment: by "processor goes down" you mean un-handled exception occurred or blackout?

Comment: my question related to both "un-handled exception occurred and blackout"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, NiFi is meant to make the data as safe as possible. Its content writing strategy is "copy on write" - meaning that the previous FlowFile's content(before the processor started processing it) is safely saved and it's only when the processor finished its task that the FlowFile starts pointing the new content.

It's also uses "write ahead log" so in case of failure, it can go back to the last known good state.

You can read more about it [here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html) or in an article I wrote [here](https://medium.com/@ben2460/about-apache-nifi-the-content-repository-b6fecce8358).

Comment: Thanks for Answer. Most of the doubt clear are now.

Comment: @AshutoshTiwari sure, if it helped you, please choose it as the answer to your question. Thanks